# UWP GridView - How to maintain visible items upon resizing (Column count changes)

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a `GridView` that I use to display **thousands** of images/thumbnails (using data binding). I used ImplicitAnimations to add transitions, so that when the control is resized and the number of columns changes - every item smoothly goes into the new position after the resize.

## Problem

This all works fine when the user is at the top of the `GridView` but becomes a problem the further the user scrolls. The further you scroll, the more items are moved around when the number of columns changes. More rows are added/removed, but the **Scrollbar is kept on the same position/offset** which causes previously visible items to go far away from the view - and the user gets lost.

### What I tried so far...

I tried working around this issue by tracking the first visible item on every scroll change event and then scrolling to it on `SizeChanged` event. The problem of this solution, however, is that it's really *rough*. Animations are no longer noticable and the whole experience is laggy.

Is there any better solution to this problem?

### Illustration of the problem

[image]

### Video example

I have also made a video to better illustrate the issue.

(The images have been blurred because some were NSFW)

[Video Link](https://streamable.com/g3gi1)

What I am looking for is a way for the scrollbar to adjust it's position on resize and stay on the same items the User was looking at - without messing up the animations.

## Edit

So apparently this can't be solved any other way but manually scrolling to the item I wish to have visible on resize, which I already tried doing and had problems with the animations being really rough again because the ScrollToItem was happening AFTER the animations were being triggered.

So my question now is - can I scroll to an item on reorder/resize - BEFORE the animations get triggered? That way I think I could keep the smoothness. Using the resize event, however, doesn't work for this.

## Edit 2 - Code sample

```
<GridView x:Name="mylist" animations:ReorderGridAnimation.Duration="600" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewSource}}">
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Loaded="ItemsWrapGrid_Loaded"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Width="300" Height="300" Background="Gainsboro">
            <Image Source="{Binding ThumbnailImage}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

GridView ItemSource is binded to the following CollectionView

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <controls:AdvancedCollectionView x:Key="viewSource" Source="{x:Bind Collection}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I switched to the Community Toolkit for the animations and the AdvancedCollectionView. The custom panel is being used for 2 reasons - to get the Panel and apply implicit animations to it - and to keep the scrollbar on the rightmost side when HorizontalAlignment is Center.

The CollectionView is binded to an ObservableCollection.

To reproduce the issue - just add a lot of items into the ItemSource and try resizing the GridView at different scroll offsets (check video sample)
.

Comment: You could try using UWP Community Toolkit `ReorderGridAnimation` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/animations/reordergrid. It is very easy to integrate, but if you need some kind of a custom animation for the reordering it won't help ..

Comment: I checked it out and it works the same way as my existing animations - so it does not solve the problem. The entire thing starts lagging when I try resizing the gridview further down and items start flying around like crazy.

Comment: can you, maybe share a gif to show the behavior ? I am using the reorder animation in my applications,it has incremental loading( and huge number of items), but it still does not lag even on a W10 mobile ..

Comment: I have added a video link.

Comment: Ok so I could reproduce the issue .. it seems that when a lot of items are loaded the animation kind of goes away..(You should report this issue in the Msft forums or uwp toolkit GitHub repo)..as for the items that are shown are getting changed because the scroll offset of the scroll viewer remains the same while the items get spread out or get stacked together .. so you need to keep track of the items that were loaded recently and *scroll them in to view*.

Comment: I edited the question. I already tried scrolling to the (tracked) items on resize but the problem was that animations got triggered before the scroll happened - which caused them to be messy again. So now I want to know if I can scroll to a specfied offset BEFORE animations get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

For your this issue, it may be caused by the [ListView and GridView UI virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview#ui-virtualization), you can try to use [VariableSizedWrapGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.VariableSizedWrapGrid) as the GridView's ItemsPanel,

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VariableSizedWrapGrid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

But it will cost much device memory and performance without virtualization. So you should also take into consideration displaying many images in once.

As for displaying the Item that the User is looking at, since there are many items displayed in the screen, the GridView does not know to track witch one.So also as @Pratyay's suggestion, you need to keep track of the item then make the ScrollView witch is in the GridView to scroll to the item.

Comment: VariableSizedWrapGrid is not an option because I definitely require virtualization for this. I already mentioned trying tracking the last visible item and then scrolling to it on resize - but the animations get messed up when doing that. The only idea I have so far, seeing how it can't be solved any other way - is scrolling to the new item BEFORE the animations get triggered, but the resize event happens after the animations. How would I go about this?

Comment: Could you provide a simple repro sample to let me see your code?

Comment: Code sample added.

Comment: If you have lots of images displayed on the screen and scroll further to the top, when you resize the window, there are so many items should reorder their position on a specific time, it would make you see the animation toughly.  But in my test, the animation looks better on the latest OS version 17134, you can have a try.